# What is the Amazon Fire Phone user_agent string?

Tags: javascript, user-agent

I am trying to find this out for my analytics software to understand.

Can anyone send me a copy of their userAgent that get display when doing something like this:
(example)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">document.write(navigator.userAgent);</script>
```

Comment: paste your question's whole title into google...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon Fire Phone User Agents are not so easy to distinguish from other mobile user agents. At the moment you could search for the occurrence of one of these strings:

- KFJWI
- KFSOWI
- KFOT
- KFTHWI
- SD4930UR
- KFTT

There are possibly even more? This list will probably change in the future with new phone versions from amazon. (So, as every time when dealing with user agents it is nothing you could count on.)

As for your exact question I compiled a example list of real user agents from various fire-phone- / browser-  / os-combinations: http://theafh.net/wp-content/uploads/amazon-fire-phone-example-user-agents.txt

I hope it helps you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

**The only direct way is to look for a 4-6 letter string starting with 'K' for Fire tablets (e.g. `KFTHWI`) and `SD4930UR` for the Fire phone.** If they release another phone perhaps it will follow a regex-friendly standard, such as `S\w\d{4}\w{2}`.

Here is a real world Amazon Fire Phone (gen 1) example browsing the web through the Facebook app, notice no mention of "silk" or "kindle":

`Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; SD4930UR Build/KTU84P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/34.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36 [FB_IAB/FB4A;FBAV/35.0.0.48.273;]`

More on identifying Silk and Kindles from Amazon: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/silk/latest/developerguide/user-agent.html